# Creating diagrams in ASCII

Tags: text, graph, ascii-art

I am looking for a program which I can use to create ASCII diagrams such these:

```
    +---------+
    |         |                        +--------------+
    |   NFS   |--+                     |              |
    |         |  |                 +-->|   CacheFS    |
    +---------+  |   +----------+  |   |  /dev/hda5   |
                 |   |          |  |   +--------------+
    +---------+  +-->|          |  |
    |         |      |          |--+
    |   AFS   |----->| FS-Cache |
    |         |      |          |--+
    +---------+  +-->|          |  |
                 |   |          |  |   +--------------+
    +---------+  |   +----------+  |   |              |
    |         |  |                 +-->|  CacheFiles  |
    |  ISOFS  |--+                     |  /var/cache  |
    |         |                        +--------------+
    +---------+
```

It should preferably be a package available in [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian). The wonderful diagram displayed above is taken from the Linux kernel documentation. I cannot believe they were created by hand. There must be some tool to create them.

Comment: You can draw this kind of diagrams from within `vim` using the [DrawIt](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=40) plugin.

Comment: *"I cannot believe they were created by hand. There must be some tool to create them."* I can easily believe they were created by hand, especially if you were, e.g., working from a sketch or other source for the diagram.  That wouldn't take more than 5 minutes.

Comment: I can quite easily believe they were created by hand because they're actually quite easy to do if you use a bit of common sense and visualise it in your head first.

Of course, it takes a few minutes longer than it would with Asciio or something.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

#### asciio

I've used [asciio](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-Asciio/lib/App/Asciio.pm) for several years. Many of the diagrams on this site I've created using `asciio`.

*example*

```
  vncviewer         .-,(  ),-.    
   __  _         .-(          )-.           gateway           vncserver 
  [__]|=|  ---->(    internet    )-------> __________ ------> ____   __ 
  /::/|_|        '-(          ).-'        [_...__...°]       |    | |==|
                     '-.( ).-'                               |____| |  |
                                                             /::::/ |__|
```

The GUI looks like this.

[image: ss of asciio]

**NOTE:** Everything is driven from the right click menu as well as short-cut keys.

#### DrawIt

Using `vim` along with the [DrawIt plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=40) you can also create basic diagrams. A good overview of how to install and use it is available here in this article titled: [How To Create ASCII Drawings in Vim Editor (Draw Boxes, Lines, Ellipses, Arrows Inside Text File)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/how-to-create-ascii-drawings-in-vim-editor-draw-boxes-lines-ellipses-arrows-inside-text-file/#more-2732).

#### asciiflow

There's a website called [asciiflow](http://asciiflow.com/) which is probably the easiest way to draw these types of diagrams.

[image: ss #2]

#### JavE

Another tool, [JavE](http://www.jave.de/), written in Java that can create ascii diagrams like this as well.

```
                                 ,'''''''''''''|
                                 | Controller  |
                                 |             |
                                 '`'i''''''''''
                                  ,'        `.
                                ,'            `.
                               -                -
                     ,'''''''''''''|      ,''''''''''''`.
                     |    Model    |______|    View     |
                     |             |      |             |
                      `''''''''''''       '`'''''''''''''
```

The GUI looks like this:

[image: ss #2]

#### Resources

- [Flytrap and Asciio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0l9W84PhOyI)
- [Installing Asciio in Ubuntu](https://web.archive.org/web/20111118093654/http://dartmouthtechnologysolutions.com:80/2010/installing-asciio-ubuntu)
- [App :: Asciio - Graphical user interface for ASCII Charts](http://perl-howto.de/2009/02/appasciio-graphische-benutzeroberflache-fur-asciicharts.html)

Comment: You could add http://diiagrams.com/ if you want

Comment: The Windows installer for asciio from the link no longer works. The installer says it got a 404 error and then aborts. I just used asciiflow instead.

Comment: @Joseph238 - thanks for the feedback, given this is Unix & Linux website I'm not sure most passer-by's will care all that much. If you come across a link to it pls let us know.

Comment: Maybe add a note about: https://textik.com/.

Comment: I recently created [AsciiGrid](https://mbarkhau.keybase.pub/asciigrid/) which uses Svgbob to render diagrams. [Here is the diagram from the original question](https://mbarkhau.keybase.pub/asciigrid/#vvF;AOAOA;ECCCgAgAEBDAAAgAgAnAmAjAnlmrAAeEWETFhzgPyihipDiymSsPgAECCeDgUTEHPMFWETFkxgWCgAgAEizhmsDg0fCOFWHfCMOHViOBi6iAjcilkIgusDiRBECCCgAgAEAAECCeDvjnajjBhRmZkAlKDjbAAREWETFjMgzeDDAhNCTEHPMFAD-kEi0hAEAAEj9nYgABnFjMq2jMn7iAEBiMjGoXqFo7hADBiMjGuNh_CCeDgUTEHPMFWEJNFKiyAAZETFfEWgDgOCCEurhAglfCWHHLfCPh_k1nUyhqMhLBECCCgAgAE1cnZji)

Comment: +1 for [asciiflow](http://asciiflow.com/)! I love its simple, easy-to-use online interface, and since it has a website you can just go to and start drawing in, it's **so** easy to get started with!

Answer (score 33):

Have a look at [artist-mode](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~tab/artist/) or [picture-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Picture-Mode.html) for Emacs (see also [this screencast](http://www.cinsk.org/emacs/emacs-artist.html)).  You might also want to check out [ditaa](http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: +1 Re: "ditaa" So someone might do these by hand so they could be converted to a graphical format...

Comment: Yes, ditaa is a great combination with asciio.

Comment: The screencast link is dead.

Answer (score 31):

I found another answer; I am not sure it is fully usable, but remember that GNU roff (groff) has a processor for the [Pic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pic_language) as well as an ascii postprocessor; thus you may have a try at something like that (if you use Linux, everything should probably already be installed). Write a file called test.roff containing:

```
.PS
box "box1";
line
box "box2";
.PE
```

Then type: `groff -Tascii -p test.roff`, and you should get:

```
+------+     +------+
|      +-----|      |
| box1 |     |box2  |
+------+     +------+
```

Regards.

Comment: One might want to [remove control characters](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/groff/2002-03/msg00047.html) by using `groff -Tlatin1 -P-c -P-b -P-u`

Comment: `groff` is preinstalled on Mac OS X :)

Comment: How to make it go down the page instead of across?

Answer (score 24):

Maybe you will be interested in [graph-easy](http://search.cpan.org/~tels/Graph-Easy/bin/graph-easy).

Example:

```
   echo "[ Bonn ] -- car --> [ Berlin ], [ Ulm ]" | graph-easy
```

produces:

```
    +--------+  car   +-----+
    |  Bonn  | -----> | Ulm |
    +--------+        +-----+
      |
      | car
      v
    +--------+
    | Berlin |
    +--------+
```

You can install it with the following commands:

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/T/TE/TELS/graph/Graph-Easy-0.64.tar.gz
tar -xzf Graph-Easy-0.64.tar.gz
cd Graph-Easy-0.64
perl Makefile.PL
make test
sudo make install
PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/libexec/perl5.12/sitebin/graph-easy
```

(Note the version numbers in the two uppermost and the last line - they may change)

Some nice screenshots are available on the pages of [lddot](http://jwilk.net/software/lddot) and [dothost](http://jwilk.net/software/dothost) (because both tools are wrappers for `graph-easy`).

Comment: Looks like the latest version is now hosted on Github: https://github.com/ironcamel/Graph-Easy

Comment: I guess this works a lot like Graphviz, but Graphviz doesn't have ASCII output which is a shame.

Comment: graph-easy uses the DOT language, the same as Graphviz

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/graph-easy

Comment: How to make it go down the page instead of across, by default?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone using a Mac (not the original poster) there's a very nice tool called [Monodraw](https://monodraw.helftone.com/).  Of course you're going to pay a few bucks for the fact that it's highly polished and powerful and intuitive, but if this is something you do often, it's a handy tool to have available and $10 is peanuts compared to the time you'll save.  If you don't do this often, there's a free trial available, so you're all set. It can even export to SVG

No, I don't work for the company.  I'm just a happy user.

Answer (score 3):

The [ADia](https://github.com/pylover/adia) project aims to render ASCII diagrams using a human-readable language:

```
diagram: Foo
sequence:
foo -> bar: Hello World!
```

Output

```
 DIAGRAM: Foo                             

 +-----+             +-----+
 | foo |             | bar |
 +-----+             +-----+
    |                   |
    |~~~Hello World!~~~>|
    |                   |
    |<------------------|
    |                   |
 +-----+             +-----+
 | foo |             | bar |
 +-----+             +-----+
```

Read the [documentation](https://pylover.github.io/adia/docs/latest/html/) or  Try the [live demo](https://pylover.github.io/adia/) page at `github.io`.

Answer (score 1):

I just used https://textik.com/ and it worked great.